# how to select desktop environment (gnome or kde or unity) before logon

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-10.04, login

I have an Ubuntu Desktop 10.04 machine running smoothly.

I downloaded the Ubuntu Unity Netbook Edition just to try out the new UI.

And that thing runs *very* slow on my machine. Each click responds after 30 seconds.

Now if I restart the laptop, it logs on straight into Unity.

I want to know about some key-combination that would allow me to select the desktop environment before logon, so that I can log in into gnome again.

Thanks,
Rishi.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the session type while login ... i had done this a long time back hence not remember the exact names ...but i think it was like ... when ubuntu ask for user name and password, there is a Session options link there, from that you can select the env. in which you wants to login.

Comment: yea thats the screen i dont get to see.. 

in my OS i had set "do not ask for password on logon".. thus it takes me straight to the desktop..

I want to see the screen that you are telling me.. how do i get there ?